# apache2 redirect app to neo4j webadmin?

Tags: url-rewriting, apache2, neo4j, proxypass

I Have a domain neodb.sample.com vhost in apache2. And i would want to redirect to neo4j webadmin (http://localhost:7474/webadmin) and also preserve the url to neodb.sample.com.

I'm not sure how to proceed with url rewrite stuff. But i was able to redirect with ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse:

```
ProxyPass /neo http://localhost:7474/webadmin
ProxyPassReverse /neo http://localhost:7474/webadmin
```

But i couldn't preserve the URL.
Could somebody help me on this.
-Deepak